# Should there be a full stop before the hyphen or dash in the sentence?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

In the excerpt:

> We look forward to witnessing their beautiful transformation by 3rd August 2017; believing that "there are no ugly women, only lazy **ones-Helena** Rubinstein".

Is there a missing full stop before the hyphen?

Can we rewrite it as,

> We look forward to witnessing their beautiful transformation by 3rd August 2017; believing that "there are no ugly women, only lazy ones." - Helena Rubinstein.

Comment: I would not use the dash here at all; I would tend to write it as *...lazy ones." (quote attributed to Helena Rubinstein)*. Ms R's name is not part of the quote being attributed to her, and should therefore not be within the quotation marks; the full stop should be included within the quoted material. The quotation itself is a full sentence; either enclose the 't' of 'there' in square brackets to indicate an edit, or quote it as originally presented, with a capital letter. *... believing that "There are no ...* or *... believing that "[t]here are no ...*

Comment: As far as I can see from Google searches, the quotes are originally used to set off the quote by HR, so should not include her name. Quotes within quotes are often problematic.

Comment: Why not parentheses instead?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Appreciate your prompt and detailed explanation. I guess my suggested rewrite shouldn't be correct too. Was trying to find a way to string them in a fluent sentence. Using brackets (quote...) seems a bit chunky but it's a good solution.
Edwin: I agree with you that quotes within quotes alw give problems. lol

Comment: I've proposed my comment above as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use the dash here at all; I would tend to write it as *...lazy ones." (quote by Helena Rubinstein)*. Ms R's name is not part of the quote being attributed to her, and should therefore not be within the quotation marks; the full stop is part of the quote, and should be included within the quoted material. The quotation itself is a full sentence; either enclose the 't' of 'there' in square brackets to indicate an edit, or quote it as originally presented, with a capital letter: *... believing that "There are no ...* or *... believing that "[t]here are no ...*

You might also consider moving the *(quote by ...)* to a footnote, depending on context.